# I am not able to set it up after full download

Tags: system-installation, iso

I downloaded the full ubuntu install .iso and I have it normally on  my PC, yet I am not able to set it up and it is saved as a normal file.

I tried to open it with many apps as file mnager, WinRar and many other apps yet it doesn't seem to do anything.

I am currently using windows 8 pro.

Comment: full duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/595510

Comment: You should burn this to a DVD and boot from it.

Comment: Or make it bootable on an USB, but you can simply follow [this guide](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)